# Regex to get price range numbers from url string

Tags: jquery, regex

I want to get only the digits from price range URL without using 'between' or 'and' in regex pathern.

```
baseurl/phones/price/between-18-and-4353/page-1/c
```

i need 18 and 4353

[Regex here](https://regex101.com/r/uholKw/4)

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/uholKw/6 try this, you will get your numbers in Group 1 and Group2 using $1 and $2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex and grab your digits from group1 and group2,

```
\bprice\b\D*(\d+)\D*(\d+)
```

Here, `\bprice\b` matches `price` as whole match and `\D*` matches zero or more non-digit characters, then `(\d+)` captures one or more digits in group1 and then again `\D*` allows matching zero or more non-digit characters and finally `(\d+)` captures the second number in group2

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/uholKw/5)**

Answer (score 0):

Regex - `/between[-](\d+)-and-(\d+)/`

Just capture both the prices into groups and you will get them in Group1 and Group2.

Regex explanation [here](https://regex101.com/r/uholKw/6)

```js
var str = "baseurl/phones/price/between-18-and-4353/page-1/c";
var pattern = /between[-](\d+)-and-(\d+)/;
var match = str.match(pattern);
var lowPrice = Number(match[1]);
var highPrice = Number(match[2]);
console.log(lowPrice, highPrice);
```

Comment: i dont want to use 'between' and 'and'. cuz it is multy language, between will be change. but ty anyway for your patient. :D

Comment: `baseurl/phones/price` will this bit remain the same ?

Answer (score 0):

I would go another route (no need for regex at all):

```js
var range = 'baseurl/phones/price/between-18-and-4353/page-1/c';
range = range.substr( range.indexOf('price/between-') ).split('-and-');
range[0] = parseInt( range[0].substr( 1 + range[0].indexOf('-') ) );
range[1] = parseInt( range[1] );

console.log( range[0], range[1] );
```